# How to check if folder exists in docker container from host

Tags: docker

I want to check if a folder exists in my docker container called `mysqlserver`. The container is a Linux machine.

the following command is working:

```
# both commands print the current working directory
docker exec -it mysqlserver pwd
# output: /
docker exec -it mysqlserver 'pwd'
# output: /
```

so i was assuming that i can check the existance of a folder like:

```
docker exec -it mysqlserver test -d /var
# output: nothing
```

even a folder that does not exist outputs nothing:

```
docker exec -it mysqlserver test -d /var
# output: nothing
```

What do i have to do to evaluate if a folder exists inside the container?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `test` command does not output anything. It simply returns 0 (true) if the test is successful, or 1 (false) if it is not.

If you require output, you'll need to chain a second command. E.g

```
test -d /var/some/dir && echo 'It Exists'
```

To do that in the container you'll need to use the shell:

```
docker exec -it mysqlserver sh -c "test -d /var/some/dir && echo 'It Exists'"
```

Pay careful attention to the quotes.

Comment: For those who wish to run this in a shell script on the host machine and have "It Exists" outputted in the host CLI, run `&& echo 'It Exists'` **after** the docker exec command, e.g. `docker exec -it mysqlserver sh -c "test -d /var/some/dir" && echo 'It Exists'`

Answer (score 4):

`test` doesn't provide an output you have to check the exit code.

```
$ test -d /var
$ echo $?
0 -> Exists

$ test -d /hello_world
$ echo $?
1 -> Doesn't exist
```

If you want to "explore" your container open an interactive session to it.

```
docker exec -ti <container_name> sh
```